# ¿Cómo configurar Apache para redireccionar fuera de mi document root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony3, mod-rewrite

Tengo mi página en Google Cloud Platform, hecha en Symfony.

Mi ruta principal es `var/www/html`. Dentro tengo una carpeta llamada `new-web` donde esta el proyecto de Symfony.

En mi archivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` tengo las siguientes líneas:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/new-web/web

    <Directory /var/www/html/new-web/web>
            AllowOverride None
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                Options -MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
        </Directory>
```

Cuando entro a mi `http://ip` funciona correctamente mostrando la página principal del proyecto Symfony.

El problema es que en la ruta `var/www/html/galeria` tengo imágenes que muestro en mi página. La forma del link es `http://ip/galeria/foto.jpg` pero dice 404 Not Found, como si `galeria` fuera un controlador y no la dirección de carpeta.

¿Cómo puedo configurar para que el servidor sepa que cuando se escribe `galeria` quiere decir la carpeta y no un controlador?

Answer (score 1):

Se soluciona agregando una nueva regla, específica para esa carpeta:

```py
RewriteEngine On

#reescribir galeria/* a var/www/html/galeria
RewriteRule ^galeria(/.*|$) /var/www/html/galeria$1

# tu regla para Symfony    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "" app.php [L]
```